# Session variable not initialized on callback from OmniAuth OpenID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, omniauth

I need to allow users of my application to associate an OpenID with their account after they are already logged in.

In the last controller visited before I defer to OmniAuth, I set the user ID to the session.  The relevant code is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def confirm
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
  end
end
```

The user then links to `/auth/openid`.  This works as expected.  Here is the OmniAuth initializer:

```
require 'openid/store/filesystem'
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :open_id, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :name => 'openid'
end
```

When the user comes back from OpenID, I route them to the sessions controller, like this (in routes.rb):

```
match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#process_omniauth'
```

Here is the relevant code from sessions_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def process_omniauth
    auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    puts "SESSION: #{session}"
    # ...
  end
end
```

The strange thing is, the `session` variable does not seem to be initialized with the user_id from the previous controller.

If I go to some other page in my application, the user_id is in session as expected.

If I try assigning the OmniAuth hash to the session variable, however, it erases whatever session was there before.  For example, if I run `session[:omniauth] = auth_hash` in the `process_omniauth` block above, this information is available in the session to other parts of my application, but the `user_id` seems to have been forgotten if I do this!

Any ideas?

Comment: @BrianMorearty - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [OmniAuth - current session not loaded on OpenID callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049994/omniauth-current-session-not-loaded-on-openid-callback)

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn Thank you. I have moved my comment to the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. What found was that when OmniAuth calls me back, `session` and `request.env['rack.session']` were both empty but `request.env['action_dispatch.request.unsigned_session_cookie']` has all the session keys.

I have not figured out why the discrepancy.

Eventually I found the answer here:

[OmniAuth - current session not loaded on OpenID callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5271761/468618).